# Perl confusion /^$key^

Tags: perl, grep

What does the /^$key/ part of this code mean? I've seen it used before in online tutorials but have no idea where and I can't find it on google.

```
if (!grep(/^$key/, @{$ignore})) {
```

earlier in the code  it states

```
my $ignore = shift;
my ($added, $field, $found, $key, $record, @records, @results, $returned, %superceded,  $value);
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Wouldn't it be that the line has to start with the value of `$key` variable?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`/^$key/` is a [regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression), aka "regex" or "regexp", a mini-language designed to match patterns.

`/.../` indicates to Perl that the contents are a regex.  `^` says to look at the beginning and `$key` puts in the contents of the variable `$key`.  So it's asking if the contents of `$key` is at the front of the string.

`grep(/^$key/, @{$ignore})` says to return all the items in the list `@$ignore` which start with `$key`.  The `!` at the front is negation, so `!grep(/^$key/, @{$ignore})` is true when `@$ignore` does *not* contain any items which start with `$key`.

You'll encounter `grep` and regular expressions a lot in Perl.  You'd be best served at this point [by reading a Perl book](http://learn.perl.org/books/) rather than trying to puzzle it out.  I'd recommend [Beginning Perl](https://www.powells.com/biblio/1118013840?&PID=25774) or [Modern Perl](http://modernperlbooks.com/books/modern_perl_2014/) (free online) or [Learning Perl](https://www.powells.com/biblio/1449303587?&PID=25774).

You can also learn about regular expressions from the Perl documentation.  Though the Perl docs can be a little dense, so I'd still recommend supplementing them with a book.

- [Perl regular expression tutorial (perlretut)](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html)
- [Perl regular expression reference (perlre)](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html)
- [grep (from perlfunc)](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep.html)
- [regex operators (from perlop)](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators).

Comment: +1 Thanks Schwern for the book recommendations.  I never quite know which ones to link to, but of course I'm amused by you linking to local Powell's :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, will have a look at the books your recommending.